# How can I get rid of top white line while loading jquery mobile page in android 4.0.3 web view page?

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, user-interface

I am getting a white border line while loading in android 4.0.3 web view a jquery mobile page,I have added a screenshot of it below.Kindly help me to resolve this issue.Thanks a lot.[image]